# Keyboard and display output incorrect on server

Tags: locale

I seem to have done something inadvertently to my server settings. It's running Ubuntu 14.04.5.

My locale settings are these:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

But since I messed up whatever I messed up, when I ssh into the server, the pipe key now types this: `ø`
And, for example, the printout of the last line after a `sudo apt-get install` of a package looks like this: `Do you want to continue? ÆY/nÅ`

And here's what the beginning of the `man` page for `locale` looks like:

```
 LOCALE(1)                                                                                                      Debian GNU/Linux                                                                                                      LOCALE(1)

NAME
       locale - Get locale-specific information.

SYNOPSIS
       locale Æ -a ⎪ -mÅ

       locale Æ -ck Å name...
```

What are those little Æ and Å characters doing in there?

I have no idea what I might've done (to deserve this!).

Any ideas how to fix it? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What terminal app are you using for SSH?

Comment: When you SSH the locale variables may be taken from your _local_ machine...

Comment: I'm using OS X terminal for ssh. The pipe key maps correctly on my local machine. Just not when I ssh to the server.

Comment: Are you using a non-UTF-8 locale on your local machine?